# Facing issue while consuming services from a class library in a API project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have created a Class library project and add the service reference of "E-Verify" web service to this project. In this project, I have created a wrapper class and consumed all the services of "E-Verify".

I have added the reference to this project in the API project. But, while assessing this wrapper method inside an API project I am getting an error
Error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'EmployerWebServiceV29.IEmployerWebServiceV29' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Anyone having any idea how to fix this issue?

**Wrapper Code:**

```
try { 
    EmployerWebServiceV29Client client = new EmployerWebServiceV29Client(); 
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ""; 
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "";
    client.VerifyConnection(); 
} catch (Exception ex) { 
    throw new ServiceAccessException(ErrorConstants.SERVICE_ACCESS_ERROR); 
}
```

**app.config:**

```
<bindings> 
    <basicHttpBinding> 
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEmployerWebServiceV29">
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"/> 
        </binding> 
    </basicHttpBinding> 
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding_IEmployerWebServiceV29">
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"> 
                <transport clientCredentialType="None"/> 
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/> 
            </security> 
        </binding> 
    </wsHttpBinding> 
</bindings>

<client>
    <endpoint address="stage.e-verify.uscis.gov/WcfWebService/…;"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEmployerWebServiceV2‌​9"
              contract="EmployerWebServiceV29.IEmployerWebServiceV29"
              name="BasicHttpBinding_IEmployerWebServiceV29"/>
    <endpoint address="stage.e-verify.uscis.gov/WcfWebService/…;"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IEmployerWebServiceV29"
              contract="EmployerWebServiceV29.IEmployerWebServiceV29"
              name="CustomBinding_IEmployerWebServiceV29"/>
</client>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the code/configuration, do not post it as comments to your own question.

Comment: Is it possible to call the services defined in a class library project inside an API project? If possible can you please suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: It is possible, yes. But you have an "unknown" issue to troubleshoot that people here won't be able to help you with unless you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question (by clicking "edit" and adding it to the body of the question) so it can be reproduced by others. The more effort you put into your question, the more likely it is you will get a sufficient answer.